# JarOptimizer from ASM tool?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

There is the `optimizer` package in the ASM. I see it is used in the build script for shrinking classes and optimizing jars, but there is no `asm-optimizer` distribution.

Since my love and trust with ASM is big, I wonder if anyone tried this optimizer on its own project?

(I am looking for a jar optimizer).

Comment: Off-topic: proguard is the de-facto standard there.

Comment: Repacking with `pack200` can do a lot of these things without the need for 3rd party tools. Only deeper code transformations need such tools but their main intention is usually not to shrink the jar. That’s only a possible side-effect.

Comment: `pack200` never worked for me since I don't want to strip the debug info; eg: `pack200 --repack --effort=9 --segment-limit=-1 --modification-time=latest myfile.jar` made almost no side reduction.

Comment: Well, if you don’t want to remove debug information, I don’t see where any optimization should come from. Optimizing code and retaining debug information at the same time does not work.

Comment: Actually there are some optimizations of bytecode; ProGuard may minimize jar for few percents.

Comment: And you are sure that these few percent are *not* the debugging information?

Comment: I think not, but I haven't got time to check. ProGuard maybe removed some methods etc. Anyway, there are some optimization techniques in bytecode, but its probably nothing significant.